# How can I add a click listener to ng-select options?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selection, angularjs-ng-repeat

If I create a select using Angular such as so:

```
<select multiple ng-model="selection" ng-options="option.name for option in getOptions()"></select>
```

How can I add an `ng-click` listener to each of the options? Is this possible, or would I have to just create the options myself using `ng-repeat`?

Comment: You don't want a click event for a select element, you want a change event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive:

```
<select multiple
        ng-change="update_select()"
        ng-model="selection"
        ng-options="option.name for option in getOptions()"></select>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.update_select = function() {
    console.log($scope.selection);
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/catalinmunteanu/9ptm5o97/)